# Create native client for Deezer on linux

Tags: sdk, deezer

I would like to develop a desktop player for Deezer using GNOME platform.

I've search and I learned that there was a C SDK but it's now unsupported.
The javascript SDK seems difficult to implement in native client. Especially with channel file that should be accessible by Deezer's servers.

I finally found that smart TVs use a specific API that rely on simple HTTP GET request to get link to the track mp3 file.
So, this is an option but it's not officially supported by Deezer and I could not manage to set the audio quality to something different from mpeg-128kbps.

So, my questions are :

- Could it be possible to access mpeg-320kbps or even FLAC using the smart TV API ?
- If not possible could I do it using the javascript SDK ? And Have you any ideas how can I implement it ?

Thanks you